# Linux: uploading unfinished files - with file size check (scp/rsync)

Tags: linux, upload, rsync, scp, filesize

I typically end up in the following situation: I have, say, a 650 MB MPEG-2 .avi video file from a camera. Then, I use [ffmpeg2theora](http://v2v.cc/~j/ffmpeg2theora/) to convert it into Theora .ogv video file, say some 150 MB in size. Finally, I want to upload this .ogv file to an `ssh` server.

Let's say, the `ffmpeg2theora` encoding process takes some 15 minutes on my PC. On the other hand, the upload goes on with a speed of about 60 KB/s, which takes some 45 minutes (for the 150MB .ogv). So: if I first encode, and wait for the encoding process to finish - and then upload, it would take approximately

```
15 min + 45 min = 1 hr
```

to complete the operation.

So, I thought it would be better if I could somehow start the upload, *in parallel* with the encoding operation; then, in principle - as the uploading process is slower (*in terms of transferred bytes/sec*) than the encoding one (*in terms of generated bytes/sec*) - the uploading process would always "trail behind" the encoding one, and so the whole operation (enc+upl) would complete in just 45 minutes (that is, just the time of the upload process +/- some minutes depending on actual upload speed situation on wire).

My **first** idea was to pipe the output of `ffmpeg2theora` to `tee` (so as to keep a local copy of the .ogv) and then, pipe the output further to `ssh` - as in:

```
./ffmpeg2theora-0.27.linux32.bin -v 8 -a 3 -o /dev/stdout MVI.AVI | tee MVI.ogv | ssh user@ssh.server.com "cat > ~/myvids/MVI.ogv"
```

While this command does, indeed, function - one can easily see in the running log in the terminal from `ffmpeg2theora`, that in this case, `ffmpeg2theora` calculates a  predicted time of completion to be 1 hour; that is, there seems to be *no* benefit in terms of smaller completion time for both enc+upl. (*While it is possible that this is due to network congestion, and me getting less of a network speed at the time - it  seems to me, that `ffmpeg2theora` has to wait for an acknowledgment for each little chunk of data it sends through the pipe, and that ACK finally has to come from `ssh`... Otherwise, `ffmpeg2theora` would not have been able to provide a completion time estimate. Then again, maybe the estimate is wrong, while the operation would indeed complete in 45 mins - dunno, never had patience to wait and time the process; I just get pissed at 1hr as estimate, and hit Ctrl-C ;) ...*)

My **second** attempt was to run the encoding process in one terminal window, i.e.:

```
./ffmpeg2theora-0.27.linux32.bin -v 8 -a 3 MVI.AVI      # MVI.ogv is auto name for output
```

..., and the uploading process, using `scp`, in another terminal window (thereby 'forcing' 'parallelization'):

```
scp MVI.ogv user@ssh.server.com:~/myvids/
```

The problem here is: let's say, at the time when `scp` starts, `ffmpeg2theora` has already encoded 5 MB of the output .ogv file. At this time, `scp` sees this 5 MB as the *entire* file size, and starts uploading - and it exits when it encounters the 5 MB mark; while in the meantime, `ffmpeg2theora` may have produced additional 15 MB, making the .ogv file 20 MB in total size at the time `scp` has exited (*finishing the transfer of the first 5 MB*).

Then I learned ([joen.dk » Tip: scp Resume](http://joen.dk/wordpress/?p=34)) that `rsync` supports 'resume' of partially completed uploads, as in:

```
rsync --partial --progress myFile remoteMachine:dirToPutIn/
```

..., so I tried using `rsync` instead of `scp` - but it seems to behave exactly the same as `scp` in terms of file size, that is: it will only transfer up to the file size read at the beginning of the process, and then it will exit.

So, my **question** to the community is: Is there a way to parallelize the encoding and uploading process, so as to gain the decrease in total processing time?

I'm guessing there could be several ways, as in:

- A command line option (that I haven't seen) that forces `scp`/`rsync` to continuously check the file size - if the file is open for writing by another process (*then I could simply run the upload in another terminal window*)
- A bash script; say running `rsync --partial` in a `while` loop, that runs as long as the .ogv file is open for writing by another process (*I don't actually like this solution, since I can hear the harddisk scanning for the resume point, every time I run `rsync --partial` - which, I guess, cannot be good; if I know that the same file is being written to at the same time*)
- A different tool (other than `scp`/`rsync`) that does support upload of a "currently generated"/"unfinished" file (*the assumption being it can handle only growing files; it would exit if it encounters that the local file is suddenly less in size than the bytes already transferred*)

... but it could also be, that I'm overlooking something - and 1hr is as good as it gets (in other words, it is maybe logically impossible to achieve 45 min total time - even if trying to parallelize) :)

Well, I look forward to comments that would, hopefully, clarify this for me ;)

Thanks in advance,
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try sshfs (http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html).This being a file system should have some optimization though I am not very sure.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but I don't think that using a filesystem instead will make much difference; essentially, because it seems in the pipe sequence: `ffmpeg2theora .. | tee .. | ssh ..` basically makes ffmpeg2theora wait until ssh has written a packet; i.e., it is still serial in nature - and even if I replace with `ffmpeg2theora .. | tee .. > /sshfs/..`, I suspect the final pipe will still "break" (as the writing is still limited by network latency). I guess I look for a way to parallelize processes as if in threads; but without coding my own C solution :)